# Setup method with signature IList<T> Get<T>(Guid id, Expression<Func<EntityName, T>> selector)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I've thoroughly searched stackoverflow for an answer to this question, but with no luck.

I've simplified my test. My issue is that I cannot get the setup of GetEntityFieldsById to work.

So this is my simplified class:

```
public class EntityClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

And a very simple repository:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    IList<T> GetEntityFieldsById<T>(Guid id, Expression<Func<EntityClass, T>> selector);
}
```

And a very simple class with the code to be tested:

```
public class CodeToTest
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public CodeToTest(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public void MethodToTest(Guid id)
    {
        var result = _repository.GetEntityFieldsById(id, x => new {x.StartDate, x.EndDate});

        //...
    }
}
```

Here I try to setup the GetEntityFieldsById method, but can't get it to work:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private Mock<IRepository> _repositoryMock;
    private CodeToTest _codeToTest;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        _repositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        _codeToTest = new CodeToTest(_repositoryMock.Object);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var fakeId = Guid.NewGuid();

        SetupGetEntityFieldsById<object>(fakeId, new List<object>());

        _codeToTest.MethodToTest(fakeId);

        // assert something
    }

    private void SetupGetEntityFieldsById<T>(Guid id, IList<T> result)
    {
        _repositoryMock.Setup(
                m => m.GetEntityFieldsById(It.Is<Guid>(p => p == id),
                    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<EntityClass, T>>>()))
            .Returns(result);
    }
}
```

As I'm using `MockBehavior.Strict` I get the classic "missing setup" error when running the test:

> Test method UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
>   Moq.MockException:
>   IRepository.GetEntityFieldsById<<>f__AnonymousType0`2>(d1b3c6fb-5a5e-4f0a-9f68-191ca6a61bff,
>   x => new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(StartDate = x.StartDate, EndDate =
>   x.EndDate)) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict. All
>   invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.

Comment: Ultimately the issue is that Moq is unable to compare and verify the expression so it faults.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with object by doing the following `var result = _repository.GetEntityFieldsById(id, x => (object)new { x.StartDate, x.EndDate });`